# UIImageView.image bigger than UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, image, imageview

I have a UIImageView in a custom tableview cell. When I set the UIimageview property, the uiimageview.image is bigger than the uiimageview. Why?
Here is the code:

```
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueMooseLogo.png"];
```

And here is a link to what the cell looks like. The blue square is the background of the imageview, and the blue moose is the image.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G7BYCriYbSGYHryP5OI7XHuVpqRKiNcBrxdY14wDgoA/edit?usp=sharing

If it's relevant, within interface builder, after I select the uiimageview, I have the view set to scale to fill.

Comment: Can you change scale to "Aspect Fit"?

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem, and tried a lot ways to fix it, finally, I did it. When you try to assign the image to your UIImageView, please resize your image as a thumbnail image, and use this thumbnail image to display. The following code just for your reference.

```
static func resizeImage(image:UIImage, toTheSize size:CGSize) -> UIImage{
    let scale = CGFloat(max(size.width/image.size.width,
    size.height/image.size.height))
    let width:CGFloat  = image.size.width * scale
    let height:CGFloat = image.size.height * scale;

    let rr:CGRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);
    image.drawInRect(rr)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You most likely want the content mode to be "Aspect Fit" not "Aspect Fill".

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that it would be a clip subviews issue.

Check your UIImageView property.

- Storyboard : check clip subviews in Attributes inspector
- Code : imgView.clipsToBounds = YES

Comment: Um. Did you set auto layout for an UIImageView? I usually set specific autolayout value(width and height) with image's dimension.

Comment: didn't work for me either. I am using auto layout with dynamic layouts