# camera image resizing

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an app I'm working on that has a function that allows the user to either take a photo or pick an image from the photo library. The code works but the image always displays larger than the `UIImageView` box. The box is set to "scale aspect fit" in the storyboard but the camera image refuses to conform.

Here's the code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{

            imageField.image = chosenImage
        } else{
            //error message goes here
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How do I get `chosenImage` to conform to the box or to aspect fit?

Comment: try with `ScaleAspectFill` and `clipsToBounds = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way please :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{

            imageField.image = chosenImage
            imageField.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
            imageField.clipsToBounds = true
        } else{
            //error message goes here
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

why  `ScaleAspectFill` and `clipsToBounds = true` have look this question [Why scale to fill give bigger image than UIImageVIew size? (using swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073097/why-scale-to-fill-give-bigger-image-than-uiimageview-size-using-swift)

if you want to more learn then check this [How to scale a UIImageView proportionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185652/how-to-scale-a-uiimageview-proportionally?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It's my pleasure mate

Answer (score 0):

The below code will resize the image captured by camera which is compatible to swift 4.0.

It checks for EXIF property of image using UIImageOrientaiton and accordind to the value of orientation, it transforms & scales the image so you will get the same return image with same orientation as your camera view orientation.

```
func scaleAndRotateImage(image: UIImage, MaxResolution iIntMaxResolution: Int) -> UIImage {
        let kMaxResolution = iIntMaxResolution
        let imgRef = image.cgImage!
        let width: CGFloat = CGFloat(imgRef.width)
        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(imgRef.height)
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        var bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        if Int(width) > kMaxResolution || Int(height) > kMaxResolution {
            let ratio: CGFloat = width / height
            if ratio > 1 {
                bounds.size.width = CGFloat(kMaxResolution)
                bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio
            }
            else {
                bounds.size.height = CGFloat(kMaxResolution)
                bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio
            }
        }
        let scaleRatio: CGFloat = bounds.size.width / width
        let imageSize = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(imgRef.width), height: CGFloat(imgRef.height))

        var boundHeight: CGFloat
        let orient = image.imageOrientation
        // The output below is limited by 1 KB.
        // Please Sign Up (Free!) to remove this limitation.

        switch orient {
        case .up:
            //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        case .upMirrored:
            //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.width, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)

        case .down:
            //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.width, y: imageSize.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))

        case .downMirrored:
            //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0.0, y: imageSize.height)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        case .leftMirrored:
            //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.height, y: imageSize.width)

            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2) / 2.0)
            break

        default: print("Error in processing image")
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        if orient == .right || orient == .left {
            context?.scaleBy(x: -scaleRatio, y: scaleRatio)
            context?.translateBy(x: -height, y: 0)
        }
        else {
            context?.scaleBy(x: scaleRatio, y: -scaleRatio)
            context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: -height)
        }
        context?.concatenate(transform)
        context?.draw(imgRef, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        let imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageCopy!
    }
```